# How to get the file size and delete file in Lua?

Tags: file, lua, size, coronasdk

I have problem in getting the size of the file using Lua. I am creating a function method that if the file size of the file is `743 bytes`, then the file will be deleted.

Here is my code :

```
local getDLFile = function(fileToDL)
            local path = system.pathForFile(fileToDL, system.DocumentsDirectory )
            local myFile = io.open( path, "w+b" ) 
            http.request{ 
                url = "http://www.testfile.com/"..fileToDL, 
                sink = ltn12.sink.file(myFile),
            }

            -- i don't know what is the syntax
            if myFile.size == 743 bytes then
                 myFile.delete
            end             

end
```

Can anyone can help me about my case?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The size is given by `myFile:seek("end")`.

To delete the file, use `os.remove(path)`. But close the file first.

Comment: thanks lhf for your answer, i try to `print(myFile:seek("end"))` but i god these error in my corona `Runtime error
        ...ne\my documents\singing idol final game\freeplay.lua:258: attempt to
use a closed file
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'seek'
        ...ne\my documents\singing idol final game\freeplay.lua:258: in function
 'getDLFile'
        ...ne\my d`

Comment: @gadss, it seems that you're closing the file before seeking when you should close it *after* seeking.

Comment: @lhf Is it necessary to seek file to previous position before `seek("end")` or does that have no impact for one-off file size getting?

Answer (score 8):

Recently Lua File System support was added to Corona! 
You can get file size using

```
local lfs = require "lfs"
local size = lfs.attributes (path, "size")
```

You can have a read here
http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/manual.html#reference

To delete the file use

```
os.remove(path)
```